# Objecitve C/Swift Pinch to Zoom into area

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiscrollview, pinchzoom

I've found plenty of pinch to zoom questions on SO, and I've been able to follow them to actually get it working, but the problem I'm having is with how it works.

When I pinch to zoom I assumed it would zoom into the area where my fingers are when I pinch. However, no matter where my fingers are located, when I pinch it zooms into the same area which happens to be the top left of my view. Is there any way to control where the zoom occurs?

For reference I'm implementing my pinch to zoom with a scrollview as followed (in Objective C, but answers can be in Swift):

```
 _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];// scrollview
 _nestedView = [[UIView alloc] init];// top level view within scrollview that contains everything
 _scrolledView = scrolledView;// the view I want to zoom into when pinching - a UIView in this case

// viewDidLoad
 self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  self.nestedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  [self.scrollView addSubview:self.nestedView];
 
  [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
  
  self.scrollView.delegate = self;
  self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;// tried with this on an off but doesn't seem to do anything
  self.scrollView.bouncesZoom = NO;
  self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
  self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
  self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;

// Delegate
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  return self.scrolledView;
}

// Constraints
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.nestedView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
      [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.nestedView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
      [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.nestedView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
      [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.nestedView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
                                            
                                            
      [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
      [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
      [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
      [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],


// scrolledView constraints
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrolledView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrolledView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrolledView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrolledView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
```

So again, the pinch to zoom happens, but it just keeps zooming into the top left of my view (scrolledView) which unfortunately makes the zooming utterly pointless for my use case.

Comment: You also need to set the content offset of the scrollview.

Comment: @skaak When do I need to set this? As the pinch gesture is being done? And how would I know what to set it to?

Comment: Wait, from the manual you get the following. *For zooming and panning to work, the delegate must implement both viewForZoomingInScrollView: and scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:; in addition, the maximum (maximumZoomScale) and minimum ( minimumZoomScale) zoom scale must be different.* My earlier comment is also not correct. I think you need that additional method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach, based on this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5758454-uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    UIImageView *imageView;
    NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewTopConstraint;
    NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewLeadingConstraint;
    NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewTrailingConstraint;
    NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewBottomConstraint;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set name of image asset here
    NSString *imageName = @"myImage";
    
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    NSAssert(img, @"Failed to load image!");

    scrollView = [UIScrollView new];
    imageView = [UIImageView new];
    
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    // respect safe area
    UILayoutGuide *g = [self.view safeAreaLayoutGuide];
    UILayoutGuide *cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide;
    
    imageViewTopConstraint = [imageView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cg.topAnchor];
    imageViewLeadingConstraint = [imageView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cg.leadingAnchor];
    imageViewTrailingConstraint = [imageView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cg.trailingAnchor];
    imageViewBottomConstraint = [imageView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cg.bottomAnchor];

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        
        [scrollView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:0.0],
        [scrollView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [scrollView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [scrollView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:0.0],

        imageViewTopConstraint,
        imageViewLeadingConstraint,
        imageViewTrailingConstraint,
        imageViewBottomConstraint,
        
    ]];
    
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    
    // this will be updated
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1;
    
    // desired max zoom scale
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
    
    imageView.image = img;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, img.size.width, img.size.height);

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self updateMinZoomScaleForSize:scrollView.bounds.size];
    [self updateConstraintsForSize:scrollView.bounds.size];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return imageView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self updateConstraintsForSize:scrollView.frame.size];
}

- (void)centerImage {
    CGFloat yOffset = (scrollView.frame.size.height - imageView.frame.size.height) * 0.5;
    CGFloat xOffset = (scrollView.frame.size.width - imageView.frame.size.width) * 0.5;
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(xOffset, yOffset);
}

- (void)updateMinZoomScaleForSize:(CGSize)size {
    UIImage *img = imageView.image;
    if (!img) {
        return;
    }
    
    CGFloat widthScale = size.width / img.size.width;
    CGFloat heightScale = size.height / img.size.height;
    
    CGFloat minScale = MIN(widthScale, heightScale);

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
    scrollView.zoomScale = minScale;
}

- (void)updateConstraintsForSize:(CGSize)size {
    CGFloat yOffset = MAX(0.0, (size.height - imageView.frame.size.height) * 0.5);
    imageViewTopConstraint.constant = yOffset;
    imageViewBottomConstraint.constant = yOffset;
    
    CGFloat xOffset = MAX(0.0, (size.width - imageView.frame.size.width) * 0.5);
    imageViewLeadingConstraint.constant = xOffset;
    imageViewTrailingConstraint.constant = xOffset;
    
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

@end
```